# Delete a row but checking two columns that are PK

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

Hello guys I am coding on VB.net. My problem is that I am deleting two rows which I do not want. I know already why is causing that. Is because in this table I have the columns called "Group", "Question" and "Order". I want to delete a question from a single group. But lets say I have the same question in 2 different groups, it will delete the question but from the two groups, which I want to delete only from the selected group. I have a label called lblGroup, I think this will be used also.

```
Dim sql As String = "Delete * from tblgroupQuestion where question = " & Val(Trim(lblQuestion.Text)) & ""
```

I am pretty sure I have to add like an "and" on this code but I am trying to research and figure out how to solve this. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if its you just want to delete the question of which is a certain group just have to do something similar to what you said with an `AND` such as:
`Dim sql As String = "Delete * from tblgroupQuestion where question = '" & Val(Trim(lblQuestion.Text)) & "' AND GROUP = '" & Val(Trim(lblGroup.Text))"'"`

Comment: No problem! If you could just accept the answer by clicking the tick beside this that would be great!